# How do I refer to the 'LXD host from an LXD container

Tags: lxd

We currently run our services in a series of LXD containers - we have one running a nginx server as a reverse proxy, pointing at each service, and where I need to connect to a container from the host or another container, I use the LXD assigned hostname. It works very well, and its extremely clean.

I'm currently looking at setting up [grafana](https://grafana.com) for monitoring in a container and hook in a prometheus instance in the host to feed it data. It would probably be helpful to be able to refer to the LXD host by a hostname - like I do for the containers for this and other projects. What would be the 'correct' way to refer to the host from a service running on a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a LXD managed network, which sets up a bridged network and also runs a dnsmasq DHCP server to provide the behaviour you describe, the host is reachable under the domain name `_gateway.<domain>`, e.g. `_gateway.lxd` (or just `_gateway` using DNS search suffixes). Requires [minimum LXD 4.16](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/weekly-status-206/11558).

If you are using any other network type, including unmanaged bridges, then there is no built-in way to do so.

Note that to actually access a service on the host using the `_gateway` name, the service must be listening on the LXD bridge interface/address.